# JAVA: Search string/keyword in the file and add the line that consist the searched string/keyword in an ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse

I have here:

```
String Path = "C:\\Ian\\sample\\install.info"
List<String> BatchList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> installList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> uninstallList = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Path);
String myLine;
int i  = 0;
while((myLine = scanner.next()) != null)
{
 if(myLine.indexOf("C:\\Batch") == 0 )
 {  
    BatchList.add(myLine);
 }
 if(myLine.indexOf("C:\\install") == 0 )
 {  
    installList.add(myLine);
 }
 if(myLine.indexOf("C:\\uninstall") == 0 )
 {  
    uninstallList.add(myLine);
 }
 i++;
}
```

Here's the content of **install.info**

```
[BatchFiles]
C:\Batch\Batch1.jar
C:\Batch\Batch2.jar
C:\Batch\Batch3.jar
C:\Batch\Batch4.jar

[INSTALL]
C:\install\sql1.sql
C:\install\sql2.sql
C:\install\sql3.sql
C:\install\sql4.sql

[UNINSTALL]
C:\uninstall\sql1.sql
C:\uninstall\sql2.sql
C:\uninstall\sql3.sql
C:\uninstall\sql4.sql
```

**Are there any ideas or any ways for me to get the line that consists of my keywords and put it in the ArrayLists?**

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

**BatchList** should consists of:

```
C:\install\Batch1.jar
C:\install\Batch2.jar
C:\install\Batch3.jar
C:\install\Batch4.jar
```

**installList** should consists of:

```
C:\install\sql1.sql
C:\install\sql2.sql
C:\install\sql3.sql
C:\install\sql4.sql
```

**uninstallList** should consists of::

```
C:\uninstall\sql1.sql
C:\uninstall\sql2.sql
C:\uninstall\sql3.sql
C:\uninstall\sql4.sql
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**UPDATE**

```
    List<String> batchList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> installList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> uninstallList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Path);
     String myLine;
     int i = 0;
     while (scanner != null && scanner.hasNext()) {
         if ((myLine = scanner.next()) != null) {
             if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\Batch") == 0) {
            batchList.add(myLine);
        }
        if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\install") == 0) {
            installList.add(myLine);
        }
        if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\uninstall") == 0) {
            uninstallList.add(myLine);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
if (scanner != null) {
    scanner.close(); // Closing scanner
}

String[] BatchPath = batchList.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] SQLinsPath = installList.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] SQLuninsPath = uninstallList.toArray(new String[0]);

for (String k : BatchPath)
{
    System.out.println(k);
}
for (String k : SQLinsPath)
{
    System.out.println(k);
}
for (String k : SQLuninsPath)
{
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: And also tell us what output you are getting. Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Yes, it shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you.

```
import java.io.File;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "C:\\Ian\\sample\\install.info"; // Changed variable name from Path to path
    File file = new File(path);                    // Creating file object
    List<String> batchList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Changed variable name from BatchList to batchList
    List<String> installList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> uninstallList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);               // Reading file object
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String myLine;
    int i = 0;
    while (scanner != null && scanner.hasNext()) {
        if ((myLine = scanner.next()) != null) {
            if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\Batch") == 0) {
                batchList.add(myLine);
            }
            if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\install") == 0) {
                installList.add(myLine);
            }
            if (myLine.indexOf("C:\\uninstall") == 0) {
                uninstallList.add(myLine);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close(); // Closing scanner
    }
    // System.out.println(batchList);
    // System.out.println(installList);
    // System.out.println(uninstallList);

    String[] BatchPath = batchList.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] SQLinsPath = installList.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] SQLuninsPath = uninstallList.toArray(new String[0]);

    System.out.println("Batch List : ");
    for (String k : BatchPath) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Install List : ");
    for (String k : SQLinsPath) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Uninstall List : ");
    for (String k : SQLuninsPath) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

**Ouptut:**

```
Batch List : 
C:\Batch\Batch1.jar
C:\Batch\Batch2.jar
C:\Batch\Batch3.jar
C:\Batch\Batch4.jar

Install List : 
C:\install\sql1.sql
C:\install\sql2.sql
C:\install\sql3.sql
C:\install\sql4.sql

Uninstall List : 
C:\uninstall\sql1.sql
C:\uninstall\sql2.sql
C:\uninstall\sql3.sql
C:\uninstall\sql4.sql
```

Comment: It shows nothing :(
Kindly see edited post for my current code.

Comment: Kindly create a file object in your code using path like `File file = new File(path);` and read that file object using scanner like `scanner = new Scanner(file);`.

Comment: The path is working, and it read the file. Output: [BatchFiles]
C:\Batch\Batch1.jar
C:\Batch\Batch2.jar
C:\Batch\Batch3.jar
C:\Batch\Batch4.jar

[INSTALL]
C:\install\sql1.sql
C:\install\sql2.sql
C:\install\sql3.sql
C:\install\sql4.sql

[UNINSTALL]
C:\uninstall\sql1.sql
C:\uninstall\sql2.sql
C:\uninstall\sql3.sql
C:\uninstall\sql4.sql

Comment: No :( the output still the same.

Comment: What output you are expecting?

Comment: BatchList should consists of:

C:\install\Batch1.jar
C:\install\Batch2.jar
C:\install\Batch3.jar
C:\install\Batch4.jar
installList should consists of:

C:\install\sql1.sql
C:\install\sql2.sql
C:\install\sql3.sql
C:\install\sql4.sql
uninstallList should consists of::

C:\uninstall\sql1.sql
C:\uninstall\sql2.sql
C:\uninstall\sql3.sql
C:\uninstall\sql4.sql

Comment: I have added output of my code in my answer, please have look at it. Are you are expecting the same output?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am expecting for output

Comment: Added your code in my code and it is giving expected output.